# Usage of "reply": Please reply to me or reply me (used in formal tone)

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-patterns, prepositional-phrases

Which usage is correct?

1. Please reply to me as soon as possible.
2. Please reply me as soon as possible.

In my understanding, people say, "Please reply my mail..." What about the ones I wrote above? I always confused by prepositions.  :P

This is the website I found online: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reply-me-soon-reply-soon.2846546/

Thank you!

Comment: The information given by [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reply): **reply**
vb (mainly intr)  ...
_2. (tr; takes a clause as object) to say (something) in answer_: he replied that he didn't want to come. >> indicates that the verb does not take a direct object (in US [and British] English), though a that-clause may be used after it. Though text-speak has its own rules (if you can call them that).

Comment: You may be mixing up *reply* with *answer*. You answer mail, but you reply to mail - even though the meaning is the same. You cannot reply mail. I am not sure if one can answer *to* mail, but it's definitely not very idiomatic.

Comment: OALD  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reply_1?q=reply

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is exceedingly basic (probably too basic for our site) and because it has been answered satisfactorily in the comments already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where you see "reply my mail". I don't encounter that in America.

[Some dictionaries](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/reply) show **reply** as only an *intransitive verb* (one that does not take a direct object).
[Some mention](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reply) a *transitive* usage, but only with a "that" clause (She replied *that* she was going to come.)

[Those that](http://ttp://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reply) include a *transitive* usage show examples where the direct object is the *content* of the reply, not the addressee or the message being responded to.

So, no, I would NOT consider

- Please reply my email [message].
  NOR
- Please reply me.

to be grammatically correct.

Both of them require "to".

Comment: Thanks, Brian. So, no matter which object after the word, "reply", I need to write "to", right?

Comment: Yes. Unless the "object" is a _that_ clause, as shown above.  Or dialogue: "That's what you think!" she replied.